# How can I convert back?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

I converted my timeseries into stationary time series with differentiation

```
data['consumption_diff'] = data.consumption-data.consumption.shift(1)
```

How can I convert `consumption_diff` back into consumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy's "r_" object which concatenates and flattens arrays and the "cumsum()" function which cumulatively sums values.

```
import numpy as np
undiffed = np.r_[data.consumption.iloc[0], data.consumption_diff.iloc[1:]].cumsum()
```

That is how you can undiff timeseries data and can be helpful if you've done a prediction into future dates that you need to undiff. However, you already have the undiffed values: `data.consumption` are your original undifffed data.